# Hypergeometric function $_2F_1(1,1;c;z)$ for $z \leq -1$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, summation, hypergeometric-function

The [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) $_2F_1(1,1;c;z)$, with $z < 0$ and $c \in (0,1)$. It can be written as a sum if $|z|  <1$:
$$
_2F_1(1,1;c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(c)_n} z^n,
$$
here $(c)_n$ is the [Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).

This series does not converge for $|z| > 1$, what does this mean for $_2F_1(1,1;c;z)$? It does still exist as an integral but can it still be written as a (different) sum?

Comment: Are you asking about the radius of convergence of $_2F_1$?

Comment: I am mainly bothered with finding an upper bound for $_2F_1(1,1;c;z)$, which I can do by using the summation form but I can't using the integral form for $z \leq 1$, I am wondering what more can be said about this function for $z \leq 1$ for example, does it still converge, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bunch of connection formulas relating hypergeometric functions at different arguments. A good source is $\S$ 15.10 (ii) [Kummer’s 24 Solutions and Connection Formulas](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.10) of **D**igital **L**ibrary of **M**athematical **F**unctions.

In general, one can express
${}_2F_1(1,1;c;z)$ for nearly all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ using other hypergeometric
functions at argument where the defining series converges.

If I didn't make any mistake in using the formula there, following is what I found.
**Please double check the formula yourself** to ensure correctness!

When $\Re z < \frac12$, we have $\left|\frac{z}{z-1}\right| < 1$. We can use DLMF 15.10.11 to get

$${}_2F_1(1,1; c; z) = (1-z)^{-1}{}_2F_1\left(1,c-1;c;\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$$

When $\Re z > \frac12$ and $c \notin \mathbb{Z}$, we have $\left|\frac{z-1}{z}\right| < 1$. We can use DLMF 15.10.21 and the Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma(c)\Gamma(1-c) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi c)}$ to get

$${}_2F_1(1,1; c; z) = \frac{c-1}{c-2} w_3(z)
+ \frac{\pi(1-c)}{\sin(\pi c)} w_4(z)
$$
where $w_3(z)$ is given by DLMF 15.10.13

$$w_3(z) = z^{-1} {}_2F_1\left(1,2-c;3-c; \frac{z-1}{z}\right)$$
and $w_4(z)$ is given by DLMF 15.10.14.

$$w_4(z) = z^{1-c}(1-z)^{c-2}{}_2F_1\left(0,c-1; c-1; \frac{z-1}{z}\right) = z^{1-c}(1-z)^{c-2}$$

Comment: I did do the calculations and it checks out!
Thanks for your answer and thanks for the reference, I saved it for later!

Comment: O wait, I do get something different for your last step $z^{1-c}(1-z)^{c-2}$ should (according to my computation) be replaced with $z^{-c}(1-z)^{c-2}$ which is, of course, only a very small error.

Comment: @HolyMonk I've double checked, using both the 1st and 3rd equalities in DLMF 15.10.14, I get $z^{1-c}(1-z)^{c-2}$.

Comment: Ok yes, I see now Thank you!